# Use of thunk for async requests(Firebase)

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux

I'm currently using react and redux as well a firebase on a project. Redux recommends the use of thunk to perform asynchronous requests. However why can't you dispatch the action as normal without a payload(since it's optional. Then perform the async call and return the state in the callback as opposed to using thunk?

Comment: `Then perform the async call and return the state in the callback` I don't know what you mean here, what callback? Redux dispatch and reducers are synchronous. That means when you do dispatch(someAction); and middleware will let someAction reach reducers then the next line you can access the sate that has been changed by reducers that handled someAction.

Comment: What I meant was why can’t one perform the async request in the reducer then return the state inside the callback